# Handing a finished website to a client, do I still keep server login credentials?

Tags: html, server, admin

I am new to website developing as a business, and am in the process of finishing up my first official website for a client. Before moving from my localhost server to a live server, I would like to know what happens after I hand off the website.

I initially have to set up the live server for the client and as such need the server administrator rights and login info. When the website is up and running. Do I just keep those passwords or does the client need to change it. It just seems like a security risk for the client, having me be able to change the contents of the server at will.

I am not saying I am going to change anything, but if I am presented with the question of whether I will be able to access the server after the deal is closed, what would I say.

Regards

Comment: Be careful with small companies that may lose passwords. I've seen it happen where the business goes back to the vendor (you) hoping you still have the admin passwords. Not good but...

Comment: Thanks will take into consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to give it back/or ask them to change it.
Then , If they need support from you , then you can request them to create a separate user with the required privileges so that you can use when ever required. Even the customer keep track/control your authentication to their system.

Answer (score 0):

Normally while handing over finished product to client, you provide all the credentials and passwords to the client.(only when the full payment has been done)
First thing they do is change all the credentials for security reasons.

And this question is more suited at this site :
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, but what I would propably change or update the website in the future? Does the same rules still apply

Comment: Do you mean "what you will do, when you need to update the website in future"?

then the client will provide you the credentials.
Consider the case when you are given a project developed by some other person, then also you will be given credentials by the client.